# Removing column names while reading content through Inputstream in Java

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader, fileoutputstream, bufferedwriter

I have been trying to remove the column names that come when I read the content of the response returned by `http get`.

Initially I used `http get` to get a content and then I read this content using `InputStream` and then write to local disk as a `csv` file using `FileOutputStream`:

```
InputStream read_content = result.getEntity().getContent();
FileOutputStream writ = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
byte[] buff = new byte[4096];
int length;
while ((length = read_content.read(buff)) > 0) {
     writ.write(buff, 0, length);
 }
```

Here `result` is the response I get from `http get`. This works fine but the problem is that the **response also contains column names which I want to remove**.

After some modification I am using this code now but the output is not coming right:

```
           InputStream read_content = result.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader reader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(read_content));

            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(path);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            reader.readLine();
            while (reader.readLine() != null) {
                out.write(reader.read());
            }
```

When I execute this modified code then **I get garbage result**. What am I doing wrong here and how can I remove the table column names?

Comment: Contains what header?

Comment: @EJP I am sorry for not being clear. Header contains table columns names

Comment: @EJP can you tell how can I use `BufferedReader.readLine()` to remove column names?

Comment: I think you are  doing it in right way but you are writing file with `reader.read()` and this reads from the First line even you called `reader.readLine()` before you write.. May be use another alternative to write the file

Comment: @looser I am sorry but I couldn't understand clearly what you meant.Some of the suggestions were to use `reader.readline()` before writing to the csv so I used it but it messed up the whole output.Can you point where I am going wrong and how can I rectify my above code to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yout code should be something like this

```
           BufferedReader br = null       ;
                   BufferedWriter out = null;
    try{

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Space/ConnTest/Test/input.txt"));
         br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
         out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C:/Space/ConnTest/Test/output.txt")));
        System.out.println("This is first line ---"+br.readLine());
        String str = "";
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            out.write(str);
        }
        System.out.println("Success");




    }
    catch(Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(br!=null)
        {
            br.close();
        }
        if(out!=null)
        {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Dont be confuse with whole code I just replaced your `out.write(reader.read());` with

```
  while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            out.write(str);
        }
```

And I am calling `br.readLine()` in `SYSOUT` so headers will get skipped. Then I am writing the file with `br.readLine()`

Comment: I tried this way.even though the first line gets removed but all the content after that gets written to the file as one line instead of multiple lines.When I was using previous way at that time I was getting all lines separately

Comment: I used `out.newline()` inside while and output looks correct now.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a line, and so is the rest of the content, use `BufferedReader.readLine(),` and skip the first line.

Comment: can you tell how can I use BufferedReader.readLine() to read through `http get` response and remove column names while writing to a `csv` file?

Comment: Err, call `readLine()` once before you start copying to the CSV?

Comment: I made modification to my code but now output is not coming right.I have modified my post above to include my updated code.Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?